# saleae logic 2 package in notebook

Tags: saleae-logic

it is my first time with saleae.
I’ve installed it on my windows machine and launch a notebook. My problem
is that I can’t create an Saleae object. Here is my code

```
import saleae
from saleae import Saleae
s = Saleae()
```

I’m having this error message:
INFO:saleae.saleae:Could not connect to Logic software, attempting to launch it now

Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

ConnectionRefusedError Traceback (most recent call last) File ....\lib\site-packages\saleae\saleae.py:211, in Saleae.init(self, host, port, quiet, args) 210 self._s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) → 211 self._s.connect((host, port)) 212 except ConnectionRefusedError: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée

how can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by reverting back to Logic 1.2.40.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).